# Save array of id's instead of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I have this HTML element:

```
<tags-input
   ng-model="film.genre"
   display-property="name"
   key-property="id"
   placeholder="Genre"
   replace-spaces-with-dashes="false">
  <auto-complete source="loadGenres($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

This creates a similar tag input field as on Stackoverflow. This is the package being used http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

Now loadGenres will return an object like so `{name: "Genre name", id: 4}`. And it will be stored into `film.genre` as such. Which is a problem because the API service expects `film.genre = [4, ...]` basically it must be an array of id's.

I'm not completely sure how to fix this. I tried to make an empty array in my `newFilm()` method loop the `film.genre` and add id's from it to that array than assign it to `film.genre`. However this does not work as when I output the film after doing that I still get an array of Objects where name: id by some logic.

What I get in film.genre:

```
"genre": [ 0: { "id": 1, "name": "Action" }, 1: { "id": 5, "name": "Comedy" }, ..]
```

What I need:

```
"genre" : [1, 5]
```

Comment: Can't you just transform the data on the way out? `film.genre.map(g => g.id)`

Comment: can you provide both array what is there and what you want?

Comment: @Phil I tried reassigning the array the way I mentioned in Service so the last place where it goes out to the API service. Same result, I also tried film.genre.map(..) but I get an error saying .map() is undefined.

Comment: @PareshGami I added what I get and what I need.

Comment: Well, in your controller it would be `$scope.film.genre` and by all accounts of the ngTagsInput documentation, it should be an array

Comment: you need to convert old array to new array using any loop

Comment: @Phil I know how to access it in controller that's not the point and I want to to be an array. I just can't send it in that format to the API service. Needs to be an array of id's not array of objects.

Comment: @PareshGami It does not work.

Comment: So why did the accepted answer work yet my first comment did not (ES6 syntax not withstanding)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### March 2019 Update

With ES2015 we can write this more succinctly.

```
const result = film.genre.map(({id}) => id);
```

#### Original Post

```
var result = film.genre.map(function(genre) {
    return genre.id;
});
```

Really should be all that you need, see the link below for a working example with your genres.

https://jsbin.com/hoxucikako/edit?js,console,output